# How to display modified value in select dropdown component of react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If I have a dropdown with some options, I am able to display it properly and select and correct value getting displayed but for my use case, I wanted a modified value to be shown. Code taken below from react official documentation -

```
class FlavorForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: 'coconut'};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('Your favorite flavor is: ' + this.state.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Pick your favorite flavor:
          <select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
            <option value="grapefruit">Grapefruit</option>
            <option value="lime">Lime</option>
            <option value="coconut">Coconut</option>
            <option value="mango">Mango</option>
          </select>
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

In the dropdown when I select `Mango`, I just want to show the first 4 letters that are selected in dropdown, in this case `Mang`. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `substring` method on your string and shorten it

```js
alert('Your favorite flavor is: ' + this.state.value.substring(0,4);
```

Comment: No, I want the dropdown menu options to have `Mango` but when dropdown is shown after selection then it should be just `Mang`. Not as an alert, but in the dropdown itself.